# How to Check if elements of two lists are equal or not using IF statement in python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have a multidimensional list. I want to check if the elements of different lists are equal or not using if statement only.
I have written different versions using for loop and while loop. I am not getting how to do the same thing using if statement only.

Below are my codes.

```
A =      [[[1], [2]],
          [[3], [4]],
          [[5], [6]],
          [[7], [8]],
          [[7], [8]]]  

# Checking if two lists are equal or not using for loop
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    if A[i] == A[i+1]:
        print('iteration',[i],'=',A[i],'and','iteration',[i+1],'=',A[i+1],'are equal')
```

Output

```
iteration [3] = [[7], [8]] and iteration [4] = [[7], [8]] are equal
```

Using while loop

```
# # Checking if two lists are equal or not using while loop
i = 1
while i in range(0, len(A)-1):
    if A[i] == A[i+1]:
        print('iteration',[i],'=',A[i],'and','iteration',[i+1],'=',A[i+1],'are equal')
    
    i = i+1
```

Output

```
iteration [3] = [[7], [8]] and iteration [4] = [[7], [8]] are equal
```

How can I achieve the same result using if statement only?

Comment: So you're trying to find consecutive duplicates in the outer list?

Comment: Yes, you can say so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use just if statements to code this. If statements cannot iterate through the length of a list when you do not know how long the list is. You need to look at each index to determine if it is equal to the index in the second list. If you did know how long the list was, you would then have to write out a different condition for each index in the list. The most efficient ways to code this would be the way you
did it(using a for loop or while loop).